# Can one upload images to google AutoML for training, using Node app?

Tags: automl, google-cloud-automl

Example: Suppose I have 10 image links, using node app I want to post this image links to AutoML and upload images, so that it can be trained later.

Comment: Yes you can, you need to specify the Google Cloud Storage links as I read from the documentation. Here - https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets/importData

Comment: What I can see so far, You must use the Google Cloud Storage and use the CSV file which contain all the links from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: @Bira Thanks man, that is correct